# Login to webpage from android app

Tags: android, http, authentication

I'm quite new in Android and today i came across a problem. I want to login to this website:

http://pedidos.pizzeriabritannia.com/index.asp?Opc=Pedir

and the retrieve some data from its source code, but certainly I don't know where to start. Could you give me some advice or some literature to deal with this issue?

Thank you mates!

I've the following code:

```
public void postLoginData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    /* login.php returns true if username and password is equal to saranga */
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://pedidos.pizzeriabritannia.com/index.asp?Opc=Pedir");

    try {
        // Add user name and password


        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "942037851"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "xxxxxx"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        Log.w("SENCIDE", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        Log.w("SENCIDE", str);

        if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
        {
         Log.w("SENCIDE", "TRUE");
         et1.setText("Login successful");   
        }else
        {
         Log.w("SENCIDE", "FALSE");
         et1.setText("Login not successful");             
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 

private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
 String line = "";
 StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
 // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
 BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
 // Read response until the end
 try {
  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
    total.append(line); 
  }
 } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 // Return full string
 return total;
}
```

Comment: what do mean by "retrieve some data from its source code"? do you want access some data in the server source code?

Comment: I want to login, and after that there's a new personal place. There, i'd like to get some information about the user.

Answer (score 0):

What you were asking for is called data scraping. You'll have to parse the return HTML to get to your value. You can make your own suitable HTML parser but I'd recommend a library for such.